# Appending text to existing word file using XWPFDocument

Tags: java, file, apache-poi, file-handling

I am trying to append a text and screenshot to the existing word file. But every time I execute the below code I am getting error as :

> > org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)    at
> >     org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.peekFirstNBytes(IOUtils.java:74)  at
> >     org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.peekFirst8Bytes(IOUtils.java:57)  at
> >     org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:135)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.verifyZipHeader(ZipHelper.java:175)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:209)
> >       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.(ZipPackage.java:98)
> >       at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
> >       at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)    at
> >     org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:116)
> >       at test.tester.(tester.java:44)   at
> >     test.tester.main(tester.java:100)
>
> failed to create file Taking first ss
>
> > java.lang.NullPointerException  at test.tester.setText(tester.java:62)
> >         at test.tester.main(tester.java:103)

Here is the code:

```
 public class tester{

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    XWPFDocument doc = null;
    // create para and run
    XWPFParagraph para = null;
    XWPFRun run = null;

    File file = null;

    public tester() {
        try {

            file = new File("WordDocWithImage.docx");

            writeToWord();
            //doc = new XWPFDocument();
            doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(file));
            //doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDocWithImage.docx"));
            para = doc.createParagraph();
            run = para.createRun();
            para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("failed to create file");
        }
    }

    public FileOutputStream writeToWord() throws FileNotFoundException {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("WordDocWithImage.docx");
        return fos;

    }

    public void setText(String text) {

        run.setText(text);
    }

    public void takeScreenshot() throws IOException, AWTException, InvalidFormatException {

        // Take screenshot
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);

        // convert buffered image to Input Stream
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "jpeg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();

        // add image to word doc
        run.addBreak();
        run.addPicture(bis, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "image file", Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(250)); // 200x200
                                                                                                                // pixels
        bis.close();

    }

    public void writeToFile() {
        try {
            // write word doc to file

            doc.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        tester t = new tester();
        try {
            System.out.println("Taking first ss");
            t.setText("First Text");
            t.takeScreenshot();
            System.out.println("Taking second ss");
            t.setText("Second Text");
            t.takeScreenshot();
            t.writeToFile();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

> The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)

The problem is about getting the **WordDocWithImage** file in this line.

```
file = new File("WordDocWithImage.docx");
```

It could not find the docx file. You should check the location of the file and give the true path in there.

EDIT: You need to change the `outputStream` to different location. You can create a subfolder. I got ss trying this.

```
public FileOutputStream writeToWord() throws FileNotFoundException {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("path/subFolder/WordDocWithImage.docx");
        return fos;

    }
```

**Note**: I have tried the code.

Comment: Can you please share the statement how you have provided the path?

Comment: created _WordDocWithImage.docx_ file in **D:** folder end give the File path like `file = new File("D:/WordDocWithImage.docx"); `

Comment: I tried but getting the same error message. can you please share your complete code you tried?

Comment: I did not change your code. It is not necessary to paste same code. Please just check the path or create new file in D folder  like me and retry

Comment: I tried creating a new file but I am getting the same error message. Did you create a new file with no data?

Comment: yeap I tried with no data docx file but guess not important

Comment: I understood. You get file and give the outputstream same same file and it gives the same error